# Is the Google cache of my site = the last time they indexed it?

Tags: google, google-cache

The Google cache of my web is a week old, and I would have expected them to have visited the site since then and indexed new content.

Does the cache lag the data collection or is it an actual indication of when the site was last crawled?

Comment: *Is the Google cache of my site = the last time they indexed it?* Yes.

Comment: However, "...is it an actual indication of when the site was last _crawled_?" - not necessarily.

Comment: Re: “I would have expected them to have visited” - Why? There are billions of websites out there and trillions of pages, you can’t expect Google to visit them all in just a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been watching the updates and there is definitely a lag.

So today (Saturday), Google posted a new cache of my site from Wednesday. The site has been updated since Wednesday. Also, the previous cache was from last Saturday, about 3-4 days previous to Wednesday.

Basically what this means is that (at least for my site) Google is visiting it every 3 days, then updating its cache 3 days later. So, there appears to be a 3-day lag between the time a site is crawled and the cache is updated.